# DeferredTask response

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have to convert an existing distributed application to google app engine in order to use it's scalability advantages for a university assignment. I'm using a DeferredTask in order to do this. Now once the task is complete (or upon failure) I'd like to send some kind of response back to the user's browser but I have no idea how to do this. The google app engine docs don't really have any info on this either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send notifications back to user take a look on [Channel API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/channel/).
Or you can try to use datastore/memcache as a communication protocol between user and GAE. User will fetch URL every N seconds, and when entity is updated by taskqueue - do something.